# How to show just one time data while use foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I made a foreach to find out the ID of the item contained because there is a product that has a special packaging, I did a foreach like this

```
else if($value['id'] != 13){ 
                        foreach ($_packaging as $key => $value) {
                            if($value->p_id != 7){
                              $img_first = '';
                              $p_name = "p_name_" . $this->config->item("language");
                              $p_price = "p_price_" . $_currency;

                              $p_info = "p_info_" . $this->config->item("language");
                              if($key == 0){
                                $img_first = 'data-img-class="first"';
                              }

                              $text_price = "FREE";
                              if($value->$p_price != 0){
                                $text_price = currency_display($value->$p_price);
                              }

                              if($value->p_manage_stock){
                                if(($value->p_stock_qty - $value->p_stock_used) >= $_total_qty){
                                  ?>
                                    <option data-img-label="<?php echo "<p class='packaging-price'>".$text_price."</p>" . "<br> <span class='packaging-info'>".$value->$p_info."</span>"; ?>" data-img-src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/packaging/'.$value->p_image); ?>"  <?php echo $img_first; ?> data-price="<?php echo $value->$p_price; ?>" value="<?php echo $value->p_id; ?>">  <?php echo $text_price; ?>  </option>
                                  <?php
                                }
                              }else{
                              ?>
                                <option data-img-label="<?php echo "<p class='packaging-price'>".$text_price."</p>" . "<br> <span class='packaging-info'>".$value->$p_info."</span>"; ?>" data-img-src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/packaging/'.$value->p_image); ?>"  <?php echo $img_first; ?> data-price="<?php echo $value->$p_price; ?>" value="<?php echo $value->p_id; ?>">  <?php echo $text_price; ?>  </option>
                              <?php
                              }
                            }
                        }
                      }
```

The Full code i save in pastebin

[Full code in this link](https://pastebin.com/m8fQQnxt)

I have 2 different products and the id != 13

[image]

but the problem is when there are 2 different products ID in the dining cart, the packaging options look double as below

[image]

What if I only want to display it once? because the id from multiple data packaging is the same?

Comment: What information allow you to say "this product and this product are the same" ? The name? An ID ? The description ? etc. If you can have multiple IDs with same product, maybe test if product have same name + price + picture + description

Comment: @MickaëlLeger because that has exclusive packaging only products with ID 13 when i show another product  except id 13, it looks like that

Comment: @MickaëlLeger please look the full link

Comment: @MickaëlLeger how to just show one time foreach?